# Set checkbox color with a color selector in Android

Tags: android, android-view, android-styles, android-checkbox

I am setting the property `buttonTint` for a `Checkbox` in my android app with a color selector to make it change color when it is checked/unchecked.

**Here is my XML for the checkbox style:**

```
<style name="standard_checkbox">
    <item name="android:layout_marginLeft">@dimen/checkbox_small_margin</item>
    <item name="android:layout_marginRight">@dimen/checkbox_small_margin</item>
    <item name="buttonTint">@color/checkbox_standard_selector</item>
</style>
```

**And here is my XML for the selector:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:state_checked="true" android:color="@color/checkbox_checked" />
    <item android:state_checked="false" android:color="@color/checkbox_unchecked" />
</selector>
```

But it isn't working properly. The `Checkbox` has the correct color when it becomes visible at first (grey). When clicked/checked, it becomes green like it should. But when it is unchecked again, it remains green for some reason.

### Edit

The problem may also be caused by my choice of theme in the manifest. I am using this customized theme:

```
<style name="Theme.Transparent.NoActionBar" parent="Theme.AppCompat.NoActionBar">
    <item name="android:windowIsTranslucent">true</item>
    <item name="android:windowBackground">@android:color/transparent</item>
    <item name="android:windowContentOverlay">@null</item>
    <item name="android:windowNoTitle">true</item>
    <item name="android:backgroundDimEnabled">false</item>
</style>
```

Comment: how do you handle color chenge on check and uncheck?

Comment: With the selector, defining different colors on different states of the checkbox (android:state_checked=true/false)

Comment: i mean in the onCheck changed method?

Comment: Ohh that.. I am not using the onchecklistener in my code.. When another button is pressed, I do something based on the checkbox state. So just calling "checkbox.isChecked()", nothing else

Comment: Why aren't you using `android` namespace for `buttonTint`? `android:buttonTint` in styles?

Comment: @azizbekian Because I am that requires min API 21. I am using API 15.

Comment: Have you tried to apply `app:buttonTint` from layout xml instead of applying from styles?

Comment: Its actually supposed to be like that with buttontint

Comment: @azizbekian Not working unfortunately.. but thanks :(

Comment: @Vygintas B How is it supposed to be like?

Comment: @user68621 Check my answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a solution, based on some of the code posted by [rafsanahmad007](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6139861/rafsanahmad007). I have created a custom checkbox view with a listener, changing the tint color based on its own state (checked or not).

Code for my custom view:

```
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.res.ColorStateList;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.support.v4.content.ContextCompat;
import android.support.v4.widget.CompoundButtonCompat;
import android.util.AttributeSet;
import android.widget.CheckBox;
import android.widget.CompoundButton;

public class CustomCheckBox extends CheckBox implements CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener {

    private OnCheckedChangeListener listener;
    private int currentColor;

    public CustomCheckBox(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
        super.setOnCheckedChangeListener(this);
        setCheckboxColor();
    }

    private void setCheckboxColor() {
        ColorStateList colorStateList = new ColorStateList(
                new int[][]{
                        new int[]{android.R.attr.state_enabled},
                },
                new int[]{
                        getCurrentColor()
                }
        );
        CompoundButtonCompat.setButtonTintList(this, colorStateList);
    }

    @Override
    public void setOnCheckedChangeListener(OnCheckedChangeListener listener) {
        this.listener = listener;
    }

    public int getCurrentColor() {
        if (isChecked()) {
            return ContextCompat.getColor(getContext(), R.color.checkbox_checked);
        } else {
            return ContextCompat.getColor(getContext(), R.color.checkbox_unchecked);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
        setCheckboxColor();
        if (listener != null) {
            listener.onCheckedChanged(buttonView, isChecked);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

try the following code: to programetically change `checkbox` button background

```
CheckBox cb = (CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.checkbox);
cb.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
    @Override
    public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
        if (isChecked) { 
            buttonView.setBackgroundColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.checked));
            }
        if (!isChecked) { 
            buttonView.setBackgroundColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.unchecked)); 
            }
    }
});
```

N.B: `getColor()` is deprecated u need to use `ContextCompat.getColor(context, R.color.color)`

**Second Way**

create a colorlist variable with your color's set

```
ColorStateList  colorStateList = new ColorStateList(
        new int[][]{
                new int[]{-android.R.attr.state_checked}, // unchecked
                new int[]{android.R.attr.state_checked} , // checked
        },
        new int[]{
                Color.parseColor("#FFFFFF"),  //unchecked color
                Color.parseColor("#009000"),  //checked color
        }
);
```

set the color using: `setButtonTintList()`

```
 CheckBox cb = (CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.checkbox);
 CompoundButtonCompat.setButtonTintList(cb,colorStateList);
```

Comment: someone having `fat brain` downvoting the working answers without a valid reason..carry on the good work..

Comment: Thanks a lot! I don't know why someone has downvoted (not me), but if this is the only solution I will have to implement my own view, extending checkbox and using the code above. I will try it out and get back to you. For now, take my upvote please :)

Comment: thankx...this is not the only solution ...it a programetically way to solve the problem which works in my case.

Comment: Sorry. This does not work as I would like it to. This changes the background color.. behind the checkbox. I need to change the color of the checkbox itself. But thanks a lot for the effort

Comment: Thanks again. But why do you have state_checked two times? Shouldn't one of them represent the unchecked state?

Comment: ooo..it is `-android.R.attr.state_checked` for unchecked state

Comment: Yes I found out.. But for some reason this is not working for me.. I think it has something to do with my choice of theme. However, I found out an alternative solution, combining some of your solution and some of my own. It will make more sense to post that as an answer, as it is the solution to my particular weird problem. But I appreciate your help and effort and will of course give you credit in my answer.

Answer (score 2):

I had same problem as you and suddenly got idea. Why not to use selector. So I tried myself and it worked.

**Solution:**

Under res folder create color folder if you don't have one and put this color selector

**checkbox_selector**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
   <item android:state_checked="true" android:color="@color/colorPrimary" />
   <item android:state_checked="false" android:color="@color/colorSecondary" />
</selector>
```

And inside your checkbox:

```
app:buttonTint="@color/checkbox_selector"
```

Comment: It is not working for me.. but thanks. It may have something to do with my choice of theme (see my edit to the question)